# Is it possible to add array elements by calling a method?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I'm a newbie, learning Object Oriented Java. I have a question regarding adding elements for multiple arrays by calling method.
I'm simply trying to avoid creating loops multiple times as for multiple arrays, I'd like to create a method which will contain necessary loops to add elements(or even displaying them as output) just so I can call it whenever I need to.
Hope you understand what I'm trying to say.
And pardon me for my poor English, regards.

Comment: I recommend reading tutorials on the topics of arrays and method parameters, e.g. [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) (both by Oracle).

Comment: You included in question what you want to do but never explained problem which you are facing. What happens when you start writing your method? What *specific* problems are you facing?

Comment: Lets maybe start with how do you want to use that method and what you expect it to do. Then try to describe your idea of how you imagine method should work and on which step(s) you have problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

you can pass array as a reference

so if you have an array named as  foo in your first function and you want to pass it to second function you can pass foo directly

please be cautious that because you are passing a reference both the functions will share same physical memory of the array

hence any modifications to foo  elements in one function will be visible on the other and vice versa